# Tab Bar Controller Navigation Xamarin with MVVM Light

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

iOS standard MVVM Light storyboard pattern is

Nav -> View Controller -> Other Views

But i want to use a tab bar controller as root view, up to here no one problems, but when i want to navigate from that tab view, in a new viewcontroller i lost the tab bar, and the view is load like a standard view and not like a "tabbed" view.

I try to create the following schema

TabBarController -> Navigation -> View -> Second View

but the mvvm light pattern put the navigation controller in a  SimpleIoc and i can't create more than once.

How i must set the storyboard ensure that i have navigation and tabbar in all the views?

Answer (score 0):

Up to now i resolve using the mvvmlight IoC for ViewModel and View, for navigation i use custom method in PageController's code behind and segue

Comment: By doing this you essentially defeat the purpose of using MVVMLight though :( Did you end up finding a better solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, by now i use xamarin.forms templates that work great.