# Use Tab bar with MVVM Light (iOS)

Tags: ios, mvvm, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have two tabs in a `UITabBarController`, both of them being `UINavigationControllers`. The problem is the Initialization of the `NavigationService` which requires a `UINavigationController` as parameter. I would like to either find a way to have tabs with a navigation controller as root, or find a way to have a tab controller as root.

I end up with three choices :

```
1. 

                /->  Ctrl 1 -> ctrl 2      
    Nav -> Tab - 
                \->  Ctrl 1 -> ctrl 2
```

This choice works, but the tab bar is lost when pushing another controller using `NavigateTo()`. This is not a solution, I do need the tabs everywhere.

```
2.
        /-> Nav -> Ctrl 1 -> ctrl 2      
   Tab - 
        \-> Nav -> Ctrl 1 -> ctrl 2
```

This simply does not work, since the `SimpleIoc` only wants a `UINavigationController`, and results in a crash. Obviously, this isn't a solution at all.

```
3.

Navigate using segue or pushing controllers manually, the 'classic' way.
```

That completely defeats the purpose of using MVVM-Light, this isn't a solution either.

I've seen [another post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32169978/3603502), and he ended up choosing option 3. I'm hoping to find something else here.

Anyone has any idea whatsoever about a possible solution to this? Or am I SOL ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't quite say option 3 Defeats the purpose of MVVM-Light, while not great it is an option - it would probably be preferable to inject the View into the ViewModel behind an interface and then use this to navigate. This way you can still control the navigation from the viewModel and it also allows you to still test the navigation portion of the viewModel since the "View" is behind an interface (can use a simple mock object here).

Another option I have seen is to just use a completely custom INavigationService that is pretty much tied to your project. You can see projects doing these at these two links:

https://github.com/losi999/XamarinSample/blob/f46e9cb1b1c152ff4510123f53b9d8bd9ddacdcf/XamarinSample.Core/Services/INavigationService.cs

https://github.com/mstein11/Happimeter/blob/691501f397a9c86d400a1fe4fe94bb866588a98e/iOS/Services/NativeNavigationService.cs

I guess if you create a custom NavigationService it would give you ultimate control, and you would also have access to history so you could choose to display viewControllers Modaly, push them or use different animations depending on the current view hierarchy.